# Free interactive graphs and charts for BlackBerry

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, graph, charts

I need to add user interactive graph to my BlackBerry application. Is there any third party library available?

I searched and found some chart engines, but the ones I found are available only as a trial version. I didn't see any free library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lot of library available for this. See following links,

- [Makelogic](http://www.makelogic.com/microGraphs/microGraphs_Home_1_1.htm)
- [J2me ChartComponent](http://www.beanizer.org/site/index.php/en/Software/J2me-ChartComponent-ver-1.5.html)
- [Tazzix](http://tazzix.com/wp/2004/03/02/j2me-chart-graph-api-v09/)
- [Java4less](http://www.java4less.com/charts/chart.php?info=j2me)